# Is kernel 5.4.y supported for RHEL6?

Tags: kernel, rhel6

We are trying to build 5.4.y for RHEL6/7/8, does anyone built the kernel 5.4.y for RHEL6? is it supported?

Answer (score 1):

RHEL 6 ships with a heavily modified 2.6.32 kernel. Considering how old is that Linux distribution (which is going EOL in some months), you can't really think of installing, and supporting, a 5.4 kernel on RHEL 6.